# How does the compiler copy member data that are arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, copy-constructor, copy-assignment

AFAIK, an array cannot be copied nor assigned so:

```
int a[5] = {1, 2};// 1 2 0 0 0
int b = a;// error
b = a; // error
```

But how does the compiler copies arrays that are member data of a class/struct type through the trivial copy-ctor and copy-assignment operator?

```
// trivial struct
struc Arr{
    int arr_[7];
};

Arr a = {5, 7, 2, 10, 9, 1, 2};
Arr b = a;// trivial cpy-ctor
a = b; // trivial cpy-assignment operator
```

- So does the compiler does something like: `this->arr_ = rhs.arr_`? Or it iterates over all elements of `rhs.arr_` and cpy-assign them to their coresponding elements in `rhs`?

Comment: Whatever happens is done in the emitted assembly code, and not at the C language level.

Comment: In this case (where the class `is_standard_layout` and `is_trivial`), the compiler will do a `memcpy`.

Comment: See the default copy constructor specification 11.4.4.2 [class.copy.ctor]: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.ctor#14, especially (14.1). The same for the copy assignment operator 11.4.5 [class.copy.assign]: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.assign#12.

Comment: You are not copying like for like when you do a=b or b=a.  b is an integer, a is an array.  You cannot copy an integer into an array or an array into an integer.

Comment: By "trivial copy-ctor" you mean a "copy constructor that beforms bitwise copy", right? Not a "compiler-generated copy constructor"?

Comment: https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/719 -- neither C and neither C++ committees have anything against relaxing C and C++ rules for native arrays.  That is an extremely important development. Please see that document -- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1997r1.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does the compiler does something like: `this->arr_ = rhs.arr_`?

No. As you said, this wouldn't compile.

> Or it iterates over all elements of `rhs.arr_` and copy-assign them to their coresponding elements in `lhs`?

For the copy assignment operator - yes.

For the copy constructor - no. There, each element is copy-**constructed** (not -assigned) from the corresponding element of the other array. Like this:

```
Arr(const Arr &other) : arr_{other.arr_[0], other.arr_[1], ..., other.arr_[6]} {}
```

This is impossible to do with a manually written loop. If you want to do it manually, you need to manually spell out each element.

But, of course, if both copy constructor and copy assignment are *trivial* (meaning they effectively copy the struct byte by byte, without doing anything else), it doesn't matter if the copy-constructor copy-constructs each element or copy-assigns it, because both do the same thing.

Note that being trivial is unrelated to being compiler-generated. The question gave me a feel that there might some confusion here.

Comment: Thank you for such good explanation. One last thing: The way you showed on copy-ctor to copy an array is interesting: `arr_{other.arr_[0], other.arr_[1], ..., other.arr_[6]}`. So If I have an array of a big size let's say 1 million elements then should I hard-code the initializers in the copy-ctor? It is really insane and whether there's a workaround? Thank you!

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa The question is why are you writing a copy constructor in the first place? [The rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) says to not do it unless absolutely necessary. You can also try using `std::array` in place of a plain array, it can be copy-constructed using just `: arr_(other.arr_)`. You could also just use a loop in the copy constructor (there will be overhead with some types, but not with trivial ones like `int`).

Comment: For example if my class needs a copy-ctor because some member data needs deep copy.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Consider wrapping that single data member in a separate class with appropriate copy constructor and assignment, then you don't need them in the class with the array.

Answer (score 2):

All arrays, and all objects, it all comes down to just bits and bytes in memory. The only difference is which, specific, bits and bytes, and how they are interpreted and used

All bits and bytes are exactly like. There are no special ones, or underprivileged ones.

And copying those bits and bytes is what a computer does. The compiler simply emits the appropriate instructions to copy the appropriate bits and bytes from one part of contiguous memory to another part of contiguous memory. Pretty much like the equivalent loop, over each value in the array, can copy it. The C++ standard does not require the compiler to implement any part of it in any specific way. The C++ standard defines the ***effects*** and the ***results*** (and the required conditions) for each part of the language. How the compiler goes about doing this, is left entirely to the compiler. You do not care about it. This is the compiler's responsibility.

It is the ***rules of the C++ programming language*** that prohibit individual arrays from getting copied in this fashion. Why that is, that would be a different question but for the purposes of this one it is merely the rules that prohibit this.

But they do allow defaulted constructors and assignment operators to effect a copy/move of array members.

A little bit later on, your C++ textbook will introduce you to the `std::array` template. You will learn to use it exactly like you would use an array. It will be very, very hard to tell the difference. It acts like an array, and properly written code will use it just like an array. But it is not an array. Therefore, it can be copied/moved exactly like you want to copy and move an equivalent array.

Comment: Yes sure for `std::array` I'me used to use it like any other STL container, it is really so powerful and overcame the limitations of a built-in array like copy/move, assign and pass it/return it to and from a function.